# By default, does an Exchange user have the ability to Export the mailbox?

Tags: exchange, exchange-2010, powershell, export

One of our contractors said that by default, it was possible for anyone to connect to the powershell instance of a CAS server and do an Export-mailbox (or similar command)

Can anyone tell me if this is correct, how it's accomplished, and how I can disable this functionality?

**More information:**

Several users on a multi tenant system will be leaving our company.  A contractor has been hired to facilitate the migration.

It's OK that people have access to OSTs and regular email but I don't want the contractor doing a bulk export of data without our coordination.  I overheard them discussing how they will need each user's password to accomplish the export.  I'm concerned if they proceed a bulk export will occur, causing contention on internet circuits and disk IO.

Comment: If they want user's passwords, they aren't planning on using powershell - they're planning on using the outlook client (or program that connects as a client) to export it all to a PST file.

Comment: I agree Grant.  They probably have some 3rd party software that connects to multiple mailboxes non-cached and does the PST export using the user's credentials.  Clunky mail admin path though...if your an Exchange consultant wanting to export mailboxes for a migration/archival then using the actual export request in the shell would be the way to go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They can export their mail locally to a PST file, but I don't see how they could gain access to a CAS server's Powershell session to Export the mailbox.

In Exchange 2010 everyone (including admins) has to be explicitly given the right to import/export.

The specific role is the "Mailbox Import Export".

Such as:

```
New-ManagementRoleAssignment –Role "Mailbox Import Export" –User BobSmith
```

So unless you've already granted that Role to all users there wouldn't be a way for a user, even if they had access to the Exchange shell on the CAS server, to run the Export request cmdlet.